# Absolute value of cross product

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors, cross-product

I just read some proof, where the identity

\begin{equation}
a^T (|b|^2 \text{id}) a - a^T (b \otimes b)a = |b \times a|^2\ \ \ \forall a,b \in \mathbb{R}^3\setminus\{0\},
\end{equation}

is used, but I do not see why this is true. When I try to compute it I get

\begin{align}
a^T (|b|^2 \text{id}) a - a^T (b \otimes b)a &= \left(
\begin{array}{c}
a_1 |b|^2\\
a_2 |b|^2\\
a_3 |b|^2\\
\end{array}
\right) \cdot a - \left(
\begin{array}{c}
\sum _{i=1}^3 a_i |b|^2\\
\sum _{i=1}^3 a_i|b|^2\\
\sum _{i=1}^3 a_i |b|^2\\
\end{array}
\right) \cdot a \nonumber \\
&= \sum _{i=1}^3 a_i^2 |b|^2 - \sum _{j=1}^3\sum _{i=1}^3 a_ia_j |b|^2.
\end{align}

In particular, this becomes negative if all $a_i$ are positive. So, is the above identity wrong or am I missing something here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can see this without computing components, though since you don't give which definition of the cross product you're using, it's unclear from context whether you have available the needed facts:

**Hint** The first term is just $|a|^2 |b|^2$, the second is $(a \cdot b)^2 = |a|^2 |b|^2 \cos^2 \theta$, where $\theta \in [0, \pi]$ is the angle between $a, b$, and $|a \times b|^2 = |a|^2 |b|^2 \sin^2 \theta$.

Comment: Thank you, I didn't have the cos identity in mind, now of course it's clear as $\text{sin}^2 = 1 - \text{cos}^2$. I'm still confused about what I did wrong in my computation, but that's not important right now.

Comment: You're welcome. At a glance, it looks like your expansion of $a^\top (b \otimes b) a^{\top}$ is wrong. We have $(b \otimes b)_{ij} = b_i b_j$, so $a^\top (b \otimes b) a = \sum_{i, j} a_i b_i b_j a_j$; NB we can rewrite this as $\left(\sum_i a_i b_i\right) \left(\sum_j a_j b_j\right) = \left(\sum_i a_i b_i\right)^2$, and the difference of the two terms on the left in your equation is positive by the Cauchy-Schwarz Inequality.

Comment: Of course, you're right, I should have seen this... thanks again!